# Regular expression to find first match only

Tags: regex, search, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, text-search

I have this text :-

```
SOME text, .....
Number of successes: 3556
Number of failures: 22
Some text, .....
Number of successes: 2623
Number of failure: 0
```

My requirement is to find the first occurrence of this pattern "Number of successes: (\d+)" which is Number of successes: 3556.
But the above expression returns subsequent matches as well.

I want the regular expression to  do this for me, unlike in java where i can use loop to iterate.

Can anyone help me with a regular expression that can find the first occurrence only.

Comment: The answer here will depend heavily on the tool or language you are using, please edit your question to include that info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution that should work in any language:

```
(?s)\A(?:(?!Number of successes:).)*Number of successes: (\d+)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)                      # Turn on singleline mode
\A                        # Start of string
(?:                       # Non-capturing group:
 (?!Number of successes:) # Unless this text intervenes:
 .                        # Match any character.
)*                        # Repeat as needed.
Number of successes:[ ]   # Then match this text
(\d+)                     # and capture the following number
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/wN6nB7).

Comment: looks nice. I wonder if it's really portable though (I work on old systems. In my solution I couldn't even use the '\d' ...)

Comment: For \d you can use [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the requirements to do it via regexp is not really a requirement, here are alternatives to the (nice) approach by Tim (who uses only regexp)

```
awk ' $0~/Number of successes: [1-9][0-9]*/ { print $0 ; exit 0 ;}'
```

or the really simple

```
grep 'Number of successes: [1-9][0-9]*' | head -1
```

I much prefer the awk one, as it quits *as soon as* it sees the first match, whereas the 2nd one could process many lines after it (until it receives the SIGPIPE or end of file)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep` with `-m` option

```
grep -m 1 'Number of successes: [0-9]\+' file
```